# Initialisation of an array of structs not compiling

Tags: c, arrays

In the code below, an array of cards compiles ok, but an array of accountants doesn't. Why? Is there a way to fix for accts?

```
struct card {
    int value;
    int cost;
};

struct accountant
{
   const char* name;
   double salary;
};

int main() {

    card cards[] = { {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3,3} };  // compiles ok

    // error C2065: '“Josh”' : undeclared identifier
    // error C2065: '“Kate”' : undeclared identifier
    // error C2065: '“Rose”' : undeclared identifier
    accountant accts[] = { {“Josh”, 2100.0}, {“Kate”, 2900.0}, {“Rose”,1700.0} };
```

}

Comment: Neither of those should work in C. There is no `card` or `accountant`. there is only `struct card` and `struct accountant`. Please post *real* code.

Comment: Those double quotes are non-standard in my opinion.

Comment: 'array of accountants' - scary..

Answer (score 9):

You might notice that in `“Josh”` the `“` and `”` aren't normal quote marks. They're often called *smart quotes*, and while they look better, they're not what the compiler is expecting. Did you copy-paste this from Microsoft Word (or similar)?

Change the quote marks to `"`.

Comment: How silly - yes you are correct.  I will close.

Comment: @AngusComber There's no reason to close your own question AFAIK.